# Parsing Through A List/Array In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have this little snippet of code I'm having a little bit of difficulty figuring out. I have a Java background, and am really new to JavaScript and React in general, so I'm having a little bit of trouble wrapping my head around this. I have this sort of 2D array I am trying to pass to my front-end, and I want to be able to parse through it to display it's values on a web page, but I don't know the syntax for it. I've tried a few things after looking at some internet resources, but I'm not sure if I'm heading down the right track. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated, sorry if this is a stupid question! Please find the code snippet below, as well as a sample output of the back-end.

```
 //define variable we want data in
    const [top10Users=[], setTop10Users] = useState();
   
    useEffect(() => {

        const getUsers = async () => {
            try {

                //getting array of top 10 Users (after await)
                const userRank = await userService.getTop10UserPoints();

                console.log(userRank);

                //setting Array of top 10 users
                setTop10Users(userRank);

            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        };

        getUsers();
    }, []);


    const listOfPaticipants = [
//for the sake of space I did not put all 10 participants here, just one, but the full code has this block 10x
        {
            "Name": {top10Users.map(top10Users => <div>{top10Users[0].firstName +" "+top10Users[0].lastName}</div>)},
            "Country": 'U.S.',
            "Points": '38,450',
            "Created": "Jan 2020"
        }
]
```

and here is the output of `console.log(userRank)`:

```
0: {firstName: 'Molly', lastName: 'Ferrari', country: 'Canada', occupation: 'STUDENT', …}
1: {firstName: 'Quandale', lastName: 'Dingle', country: 'Canada', occupation: 'STUDENT', …}
2: {firstName: 'Bulbasaur', lastName: 'User', country: 'Croatia (Hrvatska)', occupation: 'ENGINEERING', …}
3: {firstName: 'Ivysaur', lastName: 'User', country: 'American Samoa', occupation: 'UNEMPLOYED', …}
4: {firstName: 'Venusaur', lastName: 'User', country: 'Eritrea', occupation: 'SOFTWARE', …}
5: {firstName: 'Charmander', lastName: 'User', country: 'France Metropolitan', occupation: 'RELIGIOUS', …}
6: {firstName: 'Charmeleon', lastName: 'User', country: 'Bahrain', occupation: 'SOFTWARE', …}
7: {firstName: 'Charizard', lastName: 'User', country: 'Liechtenstein', occupation: 'RELIGIOUS', …}
8: {firstName: 'Squirtle', lastName: 'User', country: 'Mozambique', occupation: 'PSYCHOLOGY', …}
9: {firstName: 'Wartortle', lastName: 'User', country: 'Palau', occupation: 'MEDCINE', …}
```

Comment: use state write like `const [top10Users, setTop10Users] = useState([]);`

Comment: i can see you are doing map call for all 10. better to create a new array for fullNames just with 1 map and then reuse it (with array index)

Comment: @cmgchess How this work atm is I am using JPA repository in the backend and I am doing a findAll query, where I am returning all the top 10 users info in a JSON array, then converting it toString and sending it to the front-end. Is there no way for me to parse through all the data for what I need? When I print the back-end output to the console all the info is there and is ever separated nicely

Comment: are you hardcoding the listOfParticpants. where are Country,points,createdAt coming from

Comment: @cmgchess So for debugging's sake I am just trying to get the full name working, for now the rest is hardcoded, once I have first name working its just a matter of copy paste with a few changes for country and points and such.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-75795157-k65r8h?file=/src/index.js does this make sense

Comment: @cmgchess this would make sense absolutely if everything was hard-coded, but this is not the case. For now, the only things that are hardcoded are the Country, Points, and Created. The rest I am receiving from my back-end. I am using JPA repository to return to me a JSON array containing all the necessary, then i am .toString()'ing it. The information returned from my back end is shown above in the second code snippet. I am trying to access this information somewhat like a 2D array, as in I would say "I want first and last name from index 0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The JSX terminology is not quite right

I think you need parentheses, not "{" "}", in `name`.

Try this:

```
const listOfPaticipants = [
  {
    "Name": (
      <div>
        {top10Users.map(user => user.firstName + " " + user.lastName)}
      </div>
    ),
    "Country": 'U.S.',
    "Points": '38,450',
    "Created": "Jan 2020"
  }
]
```

#### To select one user

Don't map over all of them: just pick one.

```
const iUser = 1;

const listOfPaticipants = [
  {
    "Name": (
      <div>
        {top10Users[iUser].firstName + " " + top10Users[iUser].lastName}
      </div>
    ),
    "Country": 'U.S.',
    "Points": '38,450',
    "Created": "Jan 2020"
  }
]
```

Comment: Progress! Now my web page is displaying, however it is returning EVERY firstName, and lastName, whereas my goal would be to reference this like a sort of 2D array, so ideally I would say for example "for index 0 (first user), return to me firtsName and lastName"

Comment: Sorry this must be annoying to communicate this way, but the edited solution actually returns to me an error "user is not defined".

Comment: Sorry! I have updated it - should be `top10Users` not `user`

Answer (score 1):

you are using correct map function, but you using it wrong

Syntax for this should be like that:

```
{top10Users.map(user => (
    user.firstName
))}
```

You need to set a name for your iteration variable, in the above example it is user. And then you do not need to use brackets.

Also, you should define default value for state differently:

```
const [top10Users, setTop10Users] = useState([]);
```